# Regex pattern to match all, and return null when specific words are found

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have this Regex expression.
`^BRN.*?(?:paid|to)\s([A-Za-z\s]+)\b(?<!\bself)`

I want to it return the words after the required pattern, but only is certain words are not found. If they are found, then the Regex shouldn't return anything. Thus,

> BRN CLG-CI IQ PAID IONANDA PAUL

should return **IONANDA PAUL**, which it does. So it's correct there.
But I want

> BRN-TO CASH SELF

to return a null string or essentially it matches but returns no output. Currently, the regex returns this
**CASH\s**, the \s means a whitespace is included in the output. I tried negative lookbehind but I am still looking for how to just not return anything, if the word is found.
Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote but if you have a case-insensitive match you can ditch `A-Z` from the character class (or if it is case-sensitive update "paid" and "to" into uppercase characters since that is what your samples show).

Comment: Ah yes, it is case insensitive. I can definitely let them go, it's just become a habit now I guess. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/4k1ZnQ/2) captures the `CASH`  in `BRN-TO CASH SELF` with `([A-Za-z\s]+)\b` because once the word boundary is reached after `SELF`, the negative lookbehind triggers backtracking, and the regex engine re-matches the string and starts yielding char after char while stepping back along the string to eventually find the word boundary position right before `SELF` where no `SELF` as whole word is present immediatelty to the left of that location, and that is a valid match.

You can use a negative lookahead after `\s`:

```py
^BRN.*?(?:paid|to)\s(?![A-Za-z\s]*\bself\b)([A-Za-z\s]+)
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4k1ZnQ/1).

Now, right after matching the whitespace after `paid` or `to`, the negative lookahead check will be triggered once, and if there is a whole word `self` after any zero or more ASCII letters or whitespace chars, the whole match will fail, else, it will succeed.

Comment: Oh, now I got it why it still returns Cash after self, due to the backtracking. And triggering the check for ASCII characters once before and after is great! Definitely solves the problem I had, thanks a lot!